# Misalignment when applying responsive text

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a problem in Tailwind related to the addition of the `md:text-lg` class, as it is making my HTML misaligned.
I'm building a button, which alternates between the words `Menu` and `Hide`, but when these words reach the `md` breakpoint of Tailwind, they must have their text adjusted to the size `text-lg`.

That said, during the development process everything went well, but I still hadn't adjusted the text for this part of the `md` breakpoints. But now my code looks like this:

```
<div class="bg-blue-100">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="peer sr-only" />
    <div id="navbarMenu" class="flex cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center overflow-hidden transition-all duration-1000 before:h-0.5 before:w-24 before:bg-black after:h-0.5 after:w-24 after:bg-black peer-checked:text-[0px] peer-checked:text-transparent peer-checked:before:h-0 peer-checked:before:w-0 dark:before:bg-white dark:after:bg-white">
      <p>Menu</p>
    </div>
    <p class="flex cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center text-[0px] text-gray-700 transition-all before:h-[0px] before:w-0 peer-checked:text-base peer-checked:delay-1000 peer-checked:before:w-24 peer-checked:before:bg-black dark:text-gray-700 peer-checked:dark:dark:before:h-0.5">Hide</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

With this before and after click:

[image]

As you can see, so far everything is fine, as the input has its top and bottom next to the top and bottom of the blue bar.
But still need to add the classes `md:text-lg` and `peer-checked:md:text-lg` (the latter serves to check if the checkbox was clicked); the first to the `<div>` that contains `<p>Menu</p>` and the second to the `<p>Hide</p>` paragraph, so that the text can be adjusted when it is within the limits of the breakpoint "md".
Starting with the second case, when adding the `peer-checked:md:text-lg` class to the `<p>Hide</p>` tag, everything keeps working correctly. And right now my code is like this:

```
<div class="bg-blue-100">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="peer sr-only" />
    <div id="navbarMenu" class="flex cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center overflow-hidden transition-all duration-1000 before:h-0.5 before:w-24 before:bg-black after:h-0.5 after:w-24 after:bg-black peer-checked:text-[0px] peer-checked:text-transparent peer-checked:before:h-0 peer-checked:before:w-0 dark:before:bg-white dark:after:bg-white">
      <p>Menu</p>
    </div>
    <p class="flex cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center text-[0px] text-gray-700 transition-all before:h-[0px] before:w-0 peer-checked:text-base peer-checked:delay-1000 peer-checked:before:w-24 peer-checked:before:bg-black dark:text-gray-700 peer-checked:dark:dark:before:h-0.5 peer-checked:md:text-lg">Hide</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

[image]

However, when I apply the `md:text-lg` class to the first `<div>`, a misalignment appears in the `input` when the checkbox is clicked (after click), because the input no longer has its top and bottom next to the top and bottom of the blue bar.
Remembering once again that this only happens from the `md` breakpoint (767 pixels wide on the screen).

And finally my code is like this:

```
<div class="bg-blue-100">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="peer sr-only" />
    <div id="navbarMenu" class="flex cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center overflow-hidden transition-all duration-1000 before:h-0.5 before:w-24 before:bg-black after:h-0.5 after:w-24 after:bg-black peer-checked:text-[0px] peer-checked:text-transparent peer-checked:before:h-0 peer-checked:before:w-0 dark:before:bg-white dark:after:bg-white md:text-lg">
      <p>Menu</p>
    </div>
    <p class="flex cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center text-[0px] text-gray-700 transition-all before:h-[0px] before:w-0 peer-checked:text-base peer-checked:delay-1000 peer-checked:before:w-24 peer-checked:before:bg-black dark:text-gray-700 peer-checked:dark:dark:before:h-0.5 peer-checked:md:text-lg">Hide</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on? Why does the enlargement of the letter cause this misalignment?

Comment: This is [working as expected](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YEH5DXS6iV) to me. I can not reproduce the misalignment that you show in the image.

Comment: I just saw your example and that's not what I want to achieve.
I'll leave a link to Tailwind Play, just like you left me. LINK -> https://play.tailwindcss.com/VQoTOHj13Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look to your Tailwind Play, I found the issue. Using `md:text-lg` is changing your `line-height` as well. This messes up what you are trying to achieve.

To avoid changing the `line-height` property, you have to use `md:leading-normal`.

[Code](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YPopH7AD7g):

```html
<div class="bg-blue-100">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="peer sr-only" />
    <div id="navbarMenu" class="flex cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center overflow-hidden transition-all duration-1000 before:h-0.5 before:w-24 before:bg-black after:h-0.5 after:w-24 after:bg-black peer-checked:text-[0px] peer-checked:text-transparent peer-checked:before:h-0 peer-checked:before:w-0 dark:before:bg-white dark:after:bg-white md:text-lg md:leading-normal">
      <p>Menu</p>
    </div>
    <p class="flex cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center text-[0px] text-gray-700 transition-all before:h-[0px] before:w-0 peer-checked:text-base peer-checked:delay-1000 peer-checked:before:w-24 peer-checked:before:bg-black dark:text-gray-700 peer-checked:dark:dark:before:h-0.5 md:peer-checked:text-lg">Hide</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

You can find more about the use of `line-height` in breakpoints in [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/line-height#overriding-default-line-heights).

Comment: Hmmmm. I had already been in the `Line Height` documentation because in the `text-lg` properties this property appears as part of the class, but I confess that I didn't realize that was it.
Thank you so much, I was really stuck on this!